# Best way to maintain multiple different versions in GitHub

Tags: github, version

I just started using github, I am trying to figure out the best way to maintain multiple versions in GitHub. I've read you definitly shouldn't create branches for different versions because you won't merge them.

Where do I store these different versions? I won't ever touch them again but still want to keep them in my repository?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the versions are.

If your versions are, say, various different variants of the same website or program, usually you should use some sort of configuration or feature option and keep one version, but configurable.  You can then build or run variants based off a configuration file.

If your versions are something where you simply want to keep track of different variants, such as if you're building various procedurally generated artworks based off a common base, then you can indeed use different branches, even if you don't intend to merge them.  If your base gets updated, you can rebase your branches on top of it.  Alternately, you can keep all the variants in the same tree and factor our a common library, in which case you won't need branches except temporarily when you're working on a new variant.

If your versions are, say, different versions of your dotfiles, you can keep a main, base branch, and then keep other branches for other contexts (e.g., work) that you rebase on top of the base branch or into which you merge the base branch.

It's also fine to keep throwaway branches you might not ever use.  I have a lot of branches for my work on Git that may never get merged, or that are obsolete because somebody already built the thing I built, but better or first.  Unless it bothers you that you have extra branches that aren't progressing, there's no need to really worry about it.